# Not sure why this is happening

Tags: ruby, string

I wrote this code:

```
print "100 + 1 ="
user_answer = gets.chomp
if user_answer == 101
  puts "That's correct"
else
  puts "Sorry, you're wrong"
end
```

When I run this code, no matter what my answer is, the `else` branch is executed. If someone could point me in the correct direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try users_answer.to_i . gets returns a string. you need to convert it to an interger before comparig it to 101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user_answer` is a string:

```
user_answer = "101\n".chomp
# => "101"
```

The code is comparing a string and an number, which returns always `false`:

```
user_answer == 101
# => false
```

You need to convert the string to number, or compare it with a string:

```
user_answer.to_i == 101
# => true
user_answer == "101"
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `user_answer` as a number before comparing it to 101.

```
if user_answer.to_i == 101
  ...
```